# Using external packages in an RMD as part of an R package

Tags: r, r-markdown, r-package

## CONTEXT

I'm working on an R package with multiple RMDs to demonstrate various components i.e. detailed example, theory, etc. The RMDs are stored in an `inst` file instance as recommended, and I have functions that exist to copy them into the user's working directory so they can interact with and export content from the examples.

## ISSUE

I want one of these RMD files to use two libraries, one of which is also used in a Roxygen2 example (the other is not). Neither library is needed for the functionality of the package per se, but:

1. For the first package, the input requires several variables (which I want to show), and one of the variables necessary would be hard to compute without a very specialized function which can be found in a different package. I do not think it is within the scope of the package to implement this functionality (and if it were, it would just be a slightly-tuned alias of an external package function, which I do not think is good practice).
2. For the second package, it's the `boot` package. I just want to show an example of bootstrapping confidence intervals using my package. It's not necessary but useful, as stochastic processes are involved.

## QUESTION

What would be a good practice for including these packages in my RMD file. Obviously for the one in the Roxygen2 example, I would need it as a suggested package, but the other one does not seem to technically require it.

Should I list them as suggested packages? If I do, should I add existence checks to the RMD file to make sure that the user has them, or should I let them figure it out on their own?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Since I typically don't install `Suggested:` packages by default, I see no harm with including it in your `DESCRIPTION` as such. However, I may be the exception. Using [`requireNamespace` (or `require`)](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#search-path) would definitely allow you to provide a more specific error message. Alternatively, is there a way to not use `boot`, perhaps use some pre-stored return value from `boot` that still allows your package functions to operate? (Just a thought.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, list them as suggested packages, and check that they are installed using `requireNamespace` before using them.

I'm not sure where you saw a recommendation that you put Rmd files into `inst`; it probably makes more sense to structure them as vignettes instead, and put them in the `vignettes` directory.  This is the standard place to put documentation like that.

It isn't usually necessary to copy  them into the working directory (and it's generally considered bad practice, unless you only do so after asking, and are careful not to stomp on the user's own files).  You can use `system.file("doc/something.Rmd", package = "yourPackage")` to access them from there without copying.

Comment: The `vignettes` suggestion makes perfect sense; I wasn't really aware of it until you brought it up, but it seems like exactly what that's for. I also noticed a while ago that `system.file` does work, but my issue with it was that users could then by default knit the RMD files to HTML, etc. into the `doc` directory by default, which I assume is also bad (?). Is that bad?

Would you also recommend checking that they are installed at the beginning of the RMD file or per block where it is used? If you check it at the beginning, I assume you can just stop immediately...

Comment: Generally users shouldn't be writing into the `doc` directory where the package is stored, and on many systems normal users won't have write permission there.  If you are writing functions to knit the files with user data, you can specify that output goes to `tempdir()` or a directory selected by the user.

Comment: Awesome! I think that full answers my question! Thanks a lot!